# C# - how to close standard input and output streams on process exit?

Tags: c#, console, pipe

I have a process that needs to launch a child process and communicate with it through standard input and output.  The child process should be able to automatically terminate itself; however, I am having trouble closing the streams properly.

Here is the relevant code from the child / "client" process:

```
// This is started in a separate thread
private void watchStandardInput() {
    string line = null;
    do {
        try {
            line = Console.ReadLine();
        } catch (IOException) {
            return;
        }
        lock (inputWatcher) {
            switch (line) {
                // process command
            }
        }
    } while (line != null);
}

// This is called from the main thread
private void updateStatus(string statusMessage) {
    lock (inputWatcher) {
        Console.WriteLine(statusMessage);
    }
}
```

And here's the "server" code:

```
// This is in the main thread
using (StreamReader sr = process.StandardOutput) {
    while (!process.HasExited) {
        processOutput(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}

// Finally, commands are sent in a separate thread.
```

---

Now for the problem I am having:  When the child process is supposed to be exiting, the server stays at `sr.ReadLine()` and the client stays at `Console.ReadLine()`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is it supposed to be exiting? It looks at a glance like its just not exiting (I assume both of them waiting for input is its standard state? or is this an unusual state? At a crude level I would imagine setting a Property called "Child closing" that can be checked everywhere to ensure it doesn't try reading when it is meant to be closing but there are probably more elegant solutions, I just don't get your program flow well enough to know what they are at the moment. :)

Comment: Waiting for input is the standard state.  The child process knows when it's supposed to close, but the parent doesn't.  I could have the child do a `Console.WriteLine("Hey I'm closing")` but that's ugly and it would break existing code.

Comment: I should also mention that the child program is _trying_ to close properly - but the threads remain blocked at the calls I mentioned above.

Comment: Is the client thread with ReadLine() a background thread, or if not, are you calling Thread.Abort() on it? If not, I think Chris is right and the client app isn't closing because that thread is sitting around waiting for input.

Comment: Yes, it's a background thread, and I tried calling `Thread.Abort()` on it.  I'm well aware that the app isn't closing because that thread is sitting around waiting for input - my question is how can I get it to close?

Comment: Just set up 2 test apps to mirror this. Calling process.Kill() from the server process worked. I suspect that's still not the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the client thread doing the ReadLine() has IsBackground set to true. Do NOT do an Abort() / Join() on this thread. Just close down all non-background threads. I found that even with IsBackground set to true, doing an Abort() / Join() on the background thread caused my test app to wait for input, however, removing the Abort() / Join() and just exiting regularly worked fine.

Comment: I was able to get something working by calling `Environment.Exit` in the child process when necessary, but this is a far better solution that I was not aware of.  Thank you.